# Upgraded to Windows 10 - Macros Broken

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Problem:

I finally upgraded to Windows 10 and a few macros in Excel 2010 that I use frequently no longer work. They crash instantly when I run them and all I receive is an "**automation error**". They do not reference any outside programs/files; just lots of copy/pasting and sorting within a couple sheets. The macros seem to run on other people's computers (on Windows 10) just like they used to.

Stuff I've done:

- obligatory reboot
- Repair excel
- reinstall excel
- fiddle with macro permissions
- use copies of the workbook that work on other computers
- The weird stuff: If I create a new macro enable workbook and copy-paste in my old macros + workbook contents and try to run the macros, they work. As soon as I exit and reopen, the macros stop working.  This holds true for really simple test macros I've tried making. A macro which copies a letter from one cell to another crashes after the workbook its saved in has been closed then reopened.

I feel like I'm forgetting a few things I've tested, but this should cover most of it.

Comment: Are they referring to locations that no longer exist or have changed drive letters?

Comment: No, they don't reference anything outside the workbook. And I also tested some newly made macros that do simple things to make sure it wasn't my code.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the exact version of Excel you are using?

Comment: sure, its excel 2010

Comment: Do they get automatically executed on startup? Or do you have a custom toolbar with buttons to start them? How do you execute them normally?

Comment: I just go to view>macros and select one to run

Comment: What are your trust centers settings compared to the others that it all runs fine on?

Comment: Are the workbooks saved locally to your C: drive?

Comment: Did you move to the 64-bit version of Excel as part of the upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through a macro to see where it fails?

Comment: I was reading over what you're describing - are you sure you don't have a slight corruption going on with your OS installation? You mentioned reinstalling Excel, did you make sure you did it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not responding to comments any longer, I can only assume that with your OS upgrade, you also upgraded from 32-bit to 64-bit.

If you are declaring API calls, you will need to make them `PtrSafe`.

For example, consider the following DLL call:

```vb
Declare Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal Key As Long, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As Long) As Long
```

Any memory address pointer and window handles need to be defined as `LongPtr`, because the way 64-bit OS manage it's memory. The return type for the above function is okay to keep as `Long`, because it's not addressing the memory or a handle.

Once you make your memory pointer and window handle conversions, you then need to tell Excel that it's "safe" to use by declaring your function as `PtrSafe` (Think of "pointer safe" for the memory pointers):

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal Key As LongPtr, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As LongPtr) As Long
```

> **Take notice of the three changes** made in our declaration:
>
> > `Declare Function` *changed to* `Declare PtrSafe Function`
>
> *(This tells Excel all pointers have been changed and the function is safe to use)*
>
> > `ByVal Key As Long` *changed to* `ByVal Key As LongPtr`
>
> and finally
>
> > `ByVal NewKey As Long` *changed to* `ByVal NewKey As LongPtr`

So now the question remains. *What if I wanted to distribute this to different Operating system architectures?*

You're in luck, as VBA allows you to utilize a special `If...Then` statement for your module declarations. So for the above code, you can distribute to 32 & 64 bit OS with the following statement:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then '64-bit Office
    Declare PtrSafe Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
        ByVal Key As LongPtr, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
        ByVal Key As Long, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As Long) As Long
#End If
```